# remove excess values from dictionary c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following program to detect duplicate values and print distinct values from an integer array. but the Dictionary value prints one extra line `value 0 occurred 95 times` <- How to remove this line?

```
class CheckRepeat
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] a = new int[100];

        int n,i, j;
        Console.Write("\n\nCount total number of duplicate elements in an array:\n");
        Console.Write("---------------------------------------------------------\n");

        Console.Write("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        /*---------------------------------------Input Array-------------------------------------*/
        Console.Write("Input {0} elements in the array :\n", n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("element - {0} : ", i);
            a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        /*------------------------------------Store Duplicates-----------------------------------*/
        foreach (var value in a)
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(value))
                dict[value]++;
            else
                dict[value] = 1;
        }
        /*------------------------------------Show Duplicates-----------------------------------*/
        foreach (var pair in dict)
            Console.WriteLine("Value {0} occurred {1} times.", pair.Key, pair.Value);

        Console.WriteLine("Distinct Values");
        int[] q = a.Distinct().ToArray();
        for (i = 0; i < q.Length-1; i++) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(q[i]);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger. The array `a` initially exists of 100 zeroes, so if you enter 5 non-zero numbers, the array still contains 95 zeroes. A solution would be to initalize the array to the appropriate size _after_ asking how many numbers to enter. Or by looping over the array up till `n` instead of `foreach()`ing over all elements.

Comment: Do you *always* want to remove the entry for 0? Just use `dict.Remove(0);`

Comment: @Jon I guess not, because when the user enters 2 zeroes, the output would be expected to be "Value 0 occurred 2 times". At least that would look like a sensible requirement to this homework assignment to me.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Possibly. We really don't have enough information at the moment :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two corrections.

First, your Array is declared with Size 100. This would prefill your array with 0s. This is the reason you have the extra element (0) and its count. You could instead create the Array with same size as the desired number of elements.

```
Console.Write("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] a = new int[n]; // Change here
```

Secondly, you need correct loop condition where you print the Distinct Element

use

```
i < q.Length;
```

Instead of

```
 i < q.Length-1;
```

Complete Loop

```
for (i = 0; i < q.Length; i++) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(q[i]);
}
```

**Alternate Solution**

You could also use `List<T>` and `Linq` to make this more simpler. For example,

```
    Console.Write("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    List<int> a = new List<int>();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
            Console.Write("element - {0} : ", i);
            a.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
    }

    var dict = a.GroupBy(x=>x).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,y=>y.Count());

    Console.WriteLine("Duplicates");
    foreach(var pair in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} occured {pair.Value} times");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Distinct");
    foreach(var pair in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}");
    }
```